# How to get sum of values inside django loop

Tags: python, django, django-admin

inside my loop i am getting the values in a variable i want to get sum of these values .code is given value

```
for index in range(len(json_objects)):
getsum = 0
sum = json_objects[index]['fields']['bill']
getsum += float(sum) 
print(getsum)
```

but i am getting only values except sum can any one please help me related tihs ??

> ```
> >  json_objects[index]['fields']['bill'] i am getting values like 100
> > and 200 in a loop i want the sum 300 in getsum variable
> ```

Comment: you defined `getsum` inside the loop - move it above the `for` statement.

Comment: you're setting `getsum` to zero in each iteration, put the line `getsum = 0` before your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue has already been addressed in comments and in RHSmith159's answer -  but you may still be interested in how to write proper pythonic code...

First point: Python's `for` loop is of the `foreach` kind - you directly iterate on your list or whatever iterable instead of doing C-like indexed access. IOW, instead of

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[i])
```

the proper use is:

```
for char in lst:
    print(char)
```

Then python has a builtin `sum()` functions that takes an iterable and sums up it's values, and generator expressions that can be used to transform/filter an iterable. So your code can be reduced to one single line:

```
result = sum(float(obj["fields"]["bill"]) for obj in json_object)
```

As a side note: there's no such thing as a "json object" at runtime. JSON is a text format (IOW a string), and unserializing a json-formatted string yields a Python object - usually a dict or a list of dicts -, so `json_object` is possibly not the best possible name - the fact those data have been unserialized from some json text is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `getsum` is defined inside the loop, so it's being reset to 0 on every iteration. Move it outside of the loop and see if that helps:

```
get_sum = 0
for index in range(len(json_objects)):
    sum = json_objects[index]['fields']['bill']
    get_sum += float(sum)

print(get_sum)
```